# Adding template to garland, preprocess page doesn't work

Tags: 6, theming

So I am trying to add an additional page to garland at http://site.com/processfront, this code does not seem to run and or change the template. I know the code is being run however, since i get an error if i purposefully mess up syntax. But, I tried defining some other arbitrary variables and printing them and that didnt work either... What's going on? Thanks

function phptemplate_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  $vars['tabs2'] = menu_secondary_local_tasks();

if (arg(0) == 'processfront') {
   $variables['template_file'] = 'page-processfront';
 }

Answer (score 0):

If `processfront` is an alias for a specific node, let's say 228, then its system path is really `node/228` and `arg(0)` will be `node`.  If you've set your system up so that this node is your front page, you can just use `page-front.tpl.php` and drupal will take care of it automagically.  Otherwise, you can use `drupal_get_path_alias()` and check against that.

Comment: processfront is just an arbitrary url route I made to pull a custom php file at page-processfront.tpl.php

Comment: I want site.com/processfront to go to the custom page "page-processfront.tpl.php" I put into the theme directory

Comment: Not really following, but if you want drupal to do something at www.yoursite.com/processfront, you need to create a menu item for it.

Comment: I need to create a menu item even if it will not need to be accessed directly by users? only by script?

Comment: One side effect of page-ANY-PATH.tpl.php though is that if after you've cleared all caches/rebuilt your theme registry, it will be used for www.yoursite.com/ANY/PATH even if that path doesn't exist on your system.  This is ugly though because drupal will have returned a NOT FOUND error to the user's browser.

Comment: Not to get into extended discussions but if you are surfing to www.yoursite.com/processfront, then isn't a user accessing it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4349/discussion-between-a-funs-and-jimajamma)